# Reference: forms invariant under Lie group action give the de Rham cohomology?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

I'm looking for a reference for a proof of the following fact:

Let $G$ be a compact, connected Lie group acting on a smooth manifold $M$.
Then inclusion of the differential forms invariant under the action of $G$ 
give an isomorphism with the de Rham cohomology group.

I could not find this in Lee or Spivak, which are my go-to references.

Comment: Invariant cohomology is actually discussed in Volume 5 of Spivak, among other places.

Comment: Ah, thank you! (I only looked in Volume 1)

Comment: Basic idea, not sure where it is written down:  Forms are cohomologous to its shifts under the group action.  Averaging all of these shifts gives an invariant form cohomologous to the original.

Comment: To be precise, in Spivak vol. 5,  Look at chapter 13, section 16 pg 308,309